# FullCalendar Scheduler set to collapse by default

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying my best to dissect the scheduler code to work out how to set the parent nodes of the tree to collapsed, as in my example. I have potentially hundreds of children which do not need to be displayed. Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeSu6.png

Instead of this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGcpH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to do it by hiding the correct elements, I realised it's actually a nasty thing to do manually. Ideally, post a feature request [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues).

For now, this is the simplest and safest way by far.

```
$("#fullcalendar .fc-icon-down-triangle").each(function(i,icon){ //find all the triangle symbols
    $(icon).click(); //send a click event and let FC handle it
})
```

You might need to stick it in [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) or some other render callback.

Comment: Great, I improved it a bit so that it doesn't collapse them when a user scrolls through dates or changes the daterange (hence invoking the viewRender method).

`var loadCount = 0;
viewRender: function () {
         if (loadCount < 1) {
             $(".scheduler .fc-icon-down-triangle").each(function (i, icon) { //find all the triangle symbols
                 $(icon).click(); //send a click event and let FC handle it
             })
             loadCount++;
         }
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Man did i struggle with this. It worked to 90% but when I expanded one row the events in the children rows didn't show. The only way I got it to work 100% was to replace the **viewRender** with **eventAfterAllRender** like this:  eventAfterAllRender: function( view)

```
                { 
                 if (loadCount < 1) {
                $("#calendar .fc-icon-down-triangle").each(function(i,icon){
                  $(icon).click(); 
                     }) 

                     loadCount++; 

                     } 

                     },
```